# Whatsapp Search option does not work

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp, nokia-lumia-1520

I'm using a Lumia 1520 (Windows phone 8.1). The `Search` option in WhatsApp does not seem to work. Whenever I try to "Search Chats, contacts, and messages",  it just shows loading sign, but never really searches anything. There are no results to whatever I search either.  Can someone please help or provide any suggestions on how I can get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the app? Soft resetting the phone?

Comment: Problem might be because you are using the older version of application. Try installing the latest release. If already the latest, try re-installing.

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling WhatsApp?? It might be a problem with the whatsapp installation